# why isn't my angular options track by id working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm sure I must be doing this wrong, but:

I have an object that stores the id of an item.  I also have an array of these items.  I need to have a 'select' that represents the currently selected item, but that can also change the selected item.

I have set the 'select's model to the object.selectId.
The 'select' ng-options is "option.Text for option in options track by optionId"

Yet the model and 'select' options types don't match

How do I achieve what I need?

Here's a fiddle of what I am doing: https://jsfiddle.net/vb2xe1mc/5/

Code:

```
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.item = {
      id: 1
    };
    $scope.options = [
      {Text: "zero",  Id: 0}, 
      {Text: "one",   Id: 1}, 
      {Text: "two",   Id: 2}, 
      {Text: "three", Id: 3}
    ];

    $scope.selectChange = function() {
      alert($scope.item.id);
    };
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="myctrl">
       <select ng-model="item.id" ng-options="option.Text for option in options track by option.Id" ng-change='selectChange()'>
       </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you can, please let me know where I have gone wrong or correct the fiddle.

Thanks ^_^
Andy

Clarification:
The model item has id 1 already selected. I need the list to preselect the option with id 1 in this case. Also, When the option is selected it does not set the item.id to an int, rather it sets it to the entire option item.  I need it to set the item.id to the option.Id

Comment: The fiddle is working for me, got options zero to three. Do you want to get rid of the empty option on top?

Comment: The model item has id one already selected.  I need the list to preselect the option with id 1 in this case.  Also, When the option is selected it does not set the item.id to an int, rather it sets it to the entire option object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select ng-model="item.id" ng-options="option.id as option.Text for option in options" ng-change='selectChange()'>
```

You want to select `option.id`, not `option` and `track by` is unnecessary.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks.  I knew it had to be something simple ^_^.
Everyone else:  Thanks for your help.  The confusion was that I had over simplified the issue.  Please see the final fiddle for the full solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/vb2xe1mc/19/

Answer (score 0):

Bind the select to `ng-model="item"`, not `ng-model="item.id"`.

Also decide on `id` vs. `Id`

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <select ng-model="item" ng-options="option.Text for option in options track by option.Id" ng-change='selectChange()'>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.item = {
      Id: 1
    };
    $scope.options = [{
      Text: "zero",
      Id: 0
    }, {
      Text: "one",
      Id: 1
    }, {
      Text: "two",
      Id: 2
    }, {
      Text: "three",
      Id: 3
    }, ];

    $scope.selectChange = function() {
    console.log ($scope.item.Id)
      alert($scope.item.Id);
    };
  }]);
```

See here for a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/ax3k418p/

Comment: I just tested that in the fiddle.  It didn't work :S

Comment: Yeah, you need to use either `$scope.item.id` or `$scope.item.Id`, you are mixing both.

Comment: Ah - I see what you're doing now ^_^

Comment: I over simplified.  This is a better example: https://jsfiddle.net/vb2xe1mc/14/ The objects are quite different

Comment: Take a break and ponder what you are really trying to achieve. In that new fiddle, `$scope.item` and the items in `$scope.options` have a different data model. You can't just assign one of the `$scope.options` to  `$scope.item` and expect it to find the right one.

Comment: I don't.  That's why I'm trying to use item.id as the model ^_^
check out the answer I accepted.  it is working for me.  I'll make sure I describe my issue in more precise detail next time.  Thanks for the help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/vb2xe1mc/10/

You need to bind `item` to `ng-model`, and inititally `$scope.Id` should be set to `1` not `$scope.id = 1`

Also check when you alert it should be `alert($scope.item.Id);`

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <select ng-model="item" ng-options="option.Text for option in options" ng-change='selectChange()'>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.item = {
      Id: 1
    };
    $scope.options = [{
      Text: "zero",
      Id: 0
    }, {
      Text: "one",
      Id: 1
    }, {
      Text: "two",
      Id: 2
    }, {
      Text: "three",
      Id: 3
    }, ];

    $scope.selectChange = function() {
      alert($scope.item.Id);
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I over simplified the fiddle.  The new one better represents my issue: https://jsfiddle.net/vb2xe1mc/14/